# Can't get string char position using function IndexOf()

Tags: c#, string

When i using `String.IndexOf(C#)` to find the string `'<'`,it return -1,and how to get the position?Help me!!

This is the string:

```
[王萍 发送给您的,〈勘测设计校审卡流程〉 FA02571E3S-大唐哈尔滨第一热电厂采暖系统改造工程-[N0101]卸煤沟采暖施工图 业务|EcaClient:Cmd=OpenTask&TaskGuid={5278BE74-E1A4-4B8D-9764-B543405634A7}&UserID=178&Sender=187]
```

and what is the special char `'〈'` and try to convert it to DBC but it still not work...........

Find the reason:`'〈'` ,'<' are different

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your code. Also your title is very strange - I'm not sure what "concat" relates to.

Comment: Your string doesn't contain `<`. `<` and `〈` are not the same character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are searching different character.

Try following

```
String.IndexOf('〈')
```

Instead of

```
String.IndexOf('<')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following code will help you. Do some changes in this code as per your requirement

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string s = "[王萍 发送给您的,〈勘测设计校审卡流程〉 FA02571E3S-大唐哈尔滨第一热电厂采暖系统改造工程-[N0101]卸煤沟采暖施工图 业务|EcaClient:Cmd=OpenTask&TaskGuid={5278BE74-E1A4-4B8D-9764-B543405634A7}&UserID=178&Sender=187]";

            if (s.IndexOf("〈") != -1)
            {
                Console.Write("string contains '〈'");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Your given string contain `〈` not `<`. Make sure what you have written.